# How big can the Hausdorff dimension of a function graph get?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, dimension-theory, hausdorff-dimension

This question is inspired by [How kinky can a Jordan curve get?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23954/how-kinky-can-a-jordan-curve-get)

What is the least upper bound for the Hausdorff dimension of the graph of a real-valued, continuous function on an interval? Is the least upper bound attained by some function?

It may be noted that the area (2-dimensional Hausdorff measure) of a function graph is zero. However, this does not rule out the possible existence of a function graph of dimension two.

Comment: >>It may be noted that the area (2-dimensional Hausdorff measure) of a function graph is zero. Really?
I don't know how to prove it if the function is non-measurable.

Comment: @Catcat I had *continuous* functions in mind, as indicated in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is 2.

Besicovitch and Ursell, Sets of fractional dimensions (V): On dimensional
numbers of some continuous curves.  J. London Math. Soc. 12 (1937) 18–25. [doi:10.1112/jlms/s1-12.45.18](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-12.45.18)

Answer (score 5):

[Here's](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2003.12.100) is one example with Hausdorff dimension $2$.

Comment: Thank you. Have you checked the proof yourself? I ask because that journal (Chaos, Solitons and Fractals) has a somewhat dubious reputation (see Physics World, january 2009 and Nature, November 2008; also http://www.zeit.de/2009/03/N-El-Naschie?page=1, http://arstechnica.com/science/news/2008/11/elsevier-beyond-the-pale-of-scientific-respectability.ars), http://scienceblogs.com/pontiff/2008/11/letter_to_an_older_mathematici.php)

Comment: To follow up on my own comment, at least the paper looks serious. So I think it's probably okay.

Comment: I haven't checked it carefully. Thanks for the articles, I had never heard of this before.

Comment: 2 is the right answer, but of course 2007 is not the earliest example

Comment: I agree, it's just that I couldn't find a better example. I know of constructions that get arbitrarily close to 2, and I wonder what were the earliest examples that had dimension 2. My bet would be functions similar to the Weierstrass function.

Comment: Once you get arbitrarily close to 2, just use disjoint intervals and put graphs on them with dimensions $\gt 2-1/n$

Comment: @Gerald: Ah, but of course.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that most of the continuous functions over the unit interval have a graph of Hausdorff dimension 2. To be more precise, it is proved in https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1366030629 (The Hausdorff Dimension of Graphs of Prevalent Continuous Functions by Jonathan M. Fraser and James T. Hyde) that the set of continuous function whose graph has Hausdorff dimension 2 is prevalent.

Comment: For the earliest published results (that I know of) giving the various fractal dimensions of graphs of most (Baire category, sup norm) continuous functions, see the references in my diagram in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/44152722?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).